# UIStackView setting layoutMargins in code breaks alignment

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I'm trying to add layoutMargins to some elements in a `UIStackView` I'm creating in code.
I've tried the same thing in IB and it works perfectly, but when I add `layoutMargins` and I set `isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true` then my stack view's alignment breaks.

The code of my stack view is the following:

```
@objc lazy var buttonsStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [doneButton, separatorView, giftButton])
        stack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 4, bottom: 0, right: 4)
        stack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 44)
        stack.spacing = 4
        stack.distribution = .equalCentering
        stack.alignment = .center

        let bgView = UIView(frame: stack.bounds)
        stackViewBackground = bgView
        bgView.backgroundColor = ColorManager.shared.grayColor
        bgView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        stack.insertSubview(bgView, at: 0)

        separatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true

        return stack
    }()
```

SeparatorView only has a 1pt width constraint, while the two buttons are left unconstrained to keep their`intrinsicContentSize`.

Here's how my stackView looks when `isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement` is `false`:
[image]

But obviously, the left and right margins are needed, so when setting `isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement` to `true`, my stackview's alignment breaks:
[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot use IB for this particular view and I need to initialise it from code. Any idea on how to fix this is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The different `Distribution` options for `UIStackView` are easily misunderstood. Is your goal to have the "separator" view to be centered horizontally, and the Post and Gift buttons to be centered horizontally within each "half"? Or, is your goal to have an equal amount of ***spacing*** between elements, plus the same spacing on the left and right?

Comment: My goal is to have the two items be equally spaced form the separator, while keeping some margin at the edges of the UIStackView. `Fill` of course does not work, since it prioritizes either one of the buttons, but not both of them. Which one do you think would work?

Comment: OK - my guess is there is something wrong with the constraints / frame values you used to position the `buttonsStackView`, because setting `stack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true` doesn't change the vertical positioning when I experiment with your code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR9Lh.png ... both frames are `150 x 44`; top image is `false` bottom image is `true`

Comment: Thank you DonMag. I'll do some more experimenting, the problem must be in the layout code of the stack view itself.
Did you create your stackView using code or the IB?

Comment: I used your code... the only changes I made were 1) comment out this line `stackViewBackground = bgView` and 2) used `.lightGray` instead of your `ColorManager.shared.grayColor`

Comment: Just curious if you'd prefer this layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwWe2.png ... separator is centered horizontally and each button is centered in "its half" of the frame.

Comment: Looks very nice! I'll ask the client, so please post an answer with the code for that. However they explicitly asked for the spacing between the items and the separator to be the same (and the gift button having the minimum padding itself is not really helping in this layout)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of making that a custom view, with the `separator` centered horizontally, and the buttons centered in each "side":

```
protocol DoneGiftDelegate: class {
    func doneButtonTapped()
    func giftButtonTapped()
}

class DoneGiftView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: DoneGiftDelegate?

    let doneButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton(type: .system)
        v.setTitle("Done", for: [])
        v.tintColor = .white
        return v
    }()

    let giftButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton(type: .system)
        v.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "gift.fill"), for: [])
        v.tintColor = .white
        return v
    }()

    let separatorView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        backgroundColor = .lightGray // ColorManager.shared.grayColor

        [doneButton, separatorView, giftButton].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview($0)
        }

        // width and height constraints: 150 x 44
        //  set Priority to 999 so it can be overriden by controller if desired
        let widthConstraint = widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0)
        widthConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
        let heightConstraint = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0)
        heightConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // doneButton Leading to Leading
            doneButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            // separator Leading to doneButton Trailing
            separatorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: doneButton.trailingAnchor),
            // giftButton Leading to separator Trailing
            giftButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorView.trailingAnchor),
            // giftButton Trailing to Trailing
            giftButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),

            // all centered vertically
            doneButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            separatorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            giftButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),

            // doneButton Height = Height
            doneButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            // separator Height = 80% of Height
            separatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
            // giftButton Height = Height
            giftButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),

            // separator Width = 1
            separatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1.0),

            // doneButton Width = giftButton Width
            doneButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: giftButton.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),

            // self Width and Height
            widthConstraint,
            heightConstraint,
        ])

        // add target actions for buttons
        doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        giftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        if sender == doneButton {
            delegate?.doneButtonTapped()
        } else {
            delegate?.giftButtonTapped()
        }
    }

}

class DemoViewController: UIViewController, DoneGiftDelegate {

    let doneGiftView: DoneGiftView = DoneGiftView()

    let testView: UIView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        doneGiftView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        testView.addSubview(doneGiftView)
        view.addSubview(testView)

        // so we can see the view frame
        testView.backgroundColor = .cyan

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // testView Top: 100
            //  Leading / Trailing with 20-pts "padding"
            //  Height: 80
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),

            // doneGiftView Trailing to testView Trailing
            doneGiftView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.trailingAnchor),
            // doneGiftView centered vertically in testView
            doneGiftView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.centerYAnchor),

        ])

        doneGiftView.delegate = self
    }

    func doneButtonTapped() {
        print("Done button tapped!")
        // do what we want when Done button tapped
    }
    func giftButtonTapped() {
        print("Gift button tapped")
        // do what we want when Gift button tapped
    }
}
```

Example result:

[image]